# Wait till ajax called js countdown is ready

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My function calls and execute multiple php files after each other with `$.ajax` and `success:` for the next on etc.. So far so good.

Between some executions I want some pause with a countdown shown on the screen. Not between every file so I call occasionally a timer.php between some files in `$.ajax`.

My problem: JS gives back a success (and the next file will be executed) before the countdown is zero!

Any solution?

```
<?php
// timer.php
$p = rand(120,300); // 2 tot 5 minuten
?>
<div id="countdown"> </div>
<div id="weerverder">Weer verder...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown'),
        weerVerder = document.getElementById('weerverder'),
        seconds = <?php echo $p; ?>,
        second = 0,
        interval;

    weerVerder.style.display = 'none';

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        countdownElement.firstChild.data = 'Verwachte doorloop over ' + (seconds - second) + ' seconden...';
        if (second >= seconds) {
            weerVerder.style.display = 'block';
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        second++;
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

The requested AJAX part (test)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var u, t;
    var url = [
        "",
        "timer.php",
        "test.php",
        "timer.php",
        "test.php",
        "test.php",
        "test.php",
        "timer.php",
        "test.php"
    ];

    function startup(u, t) {

        $.ajax({
            url: url[u],
            type: 'POST',
            data: '',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 3600000, // timeout: 1 uur, security reason when hanging
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                if(status == 'success') {
                    $('#display').append(response + '<br>');
                    u+=1;
                    if(u < t) {
                        startup(u, t);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#display').append('Klaar!<br>');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert(status+ ' - '+ xhr.status);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    startup(1, 9)

});
```

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work for me. Could you maybe also add the code of the AJAX?

Comment: Yes, the timer.php code, called from a $.ajax script works but it is a success in $.ajax before the timer ends.

Comment: @rvalerio > `var a, b;` means a is local indeed, however b will be global < this is wrong ! it is different from `var a; b`

Comment: @Anonymous0day true, you are correct, but my confusion didn't come from there, I made a huge mistake and confused with var a = b = 1 for example, which has the behaviour I said. Will remove the comment to avoid misleading anyone.